# Override checkout shipping/billing detail section

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, customer-address

I have encrypted customer ,shipping/billing address , now I want to show decrypted customer address on checkout shipping page section , I have tried with plugin on process no success.

Please suggest any other function that renders customer address or event for overriding this billing/shipping section to get decrypted customer address